# Finding the f(x) in a Fourier series

Tags: fourier-series

Given the following question:

> The function $f(x)$ is defined by
>   $$ f(x)= \begin{cases} 2x& \textrm{if} \ 0 \leq x<\dfrac{\pi}{3} \\ \pi - x & \textrm{if} \ \dfrac{\pi}{3}\leq x \leq \pi \end{cases} $$

Also given the following info:

> $f(-x)=-f(x) = f(x+2\pi)$

I know that the graph is a triangle wave form and it repeats every 2 period. I also know it is odd and to use $$b_n=\frac{1}{L}\int_{-L}^L f(x) \sin \left(\frac{n\pi}{L}x\right)\ dx$$
The problem I have is I don't know how to find the $f(x)$ value. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $f(x)$ was given to you right there in the problem statement
$$ 
f(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{lr}
 2x & 0\leq x < \frac{\pi}{3} \\
 \pi - x & \frac{\pi}{3} \leq x \leq \pi
\end{array}
\right.
$$

You have to split up your integration region like $$\int_0^{\pi} = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{3}}+ \int_{\frac{\pi}{3}}^{\pi}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't want to solve your problem, but try to give you some hints.

Your function is a pice-wise defined function, so you musn't expect an expression like $f(x)=2x+3/2$, but an expression like

$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
2x, & \mbox{when } 0\leq x<\pi/3 \\
\pi-x & \mbox{when } \pi/3\leq x<\pi .
\end{cases}
$$

On the other hand, they tell you your function is odd ($f(-x)=-f(x)$), so you can achive a similar expresion but when $x$ is in $[-\pi,0]$ (try it).

Your total function will be the ''paste'' of two data, and is defined only on $[-L,L]$, $L=\pi$. The Fourier series extends it to the whole real line.

Now, how do yo compute coefficients? Well, since the function is odd you know that the only coefficients of $\sin$ matters. All you have to do it now is divide your integral in ''little'' integrals where you have an expression like $x^2$ for you function. I mean, cut the intergal interval $[-L,L]$ in some short intervals.

Finally, note that the argument is an even function (is the product of two odd) and is integred in a symmetric interval. Then you can reduce your above to expression to

$$
b_n=\frac{2}{L}\int_0^L f(x) \sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right) dx.
$$

PD: To get the symbol $\pi$ you must type `\pi`. Similar, for $\leq$ or $\geq$ you have to type `\leq` (Less or EQual) and `\geq` (Great or EQual), respectively.

Comment: so ultimately I would get an equation of type $$b_n=\frac{2}{\pi}[\int_{0}^\frac{\pi}/3 2xsin(\frac{nx\pi}{\pi})}+\int_{\frac{\pi}{3}}^{\pi}(\pi-x)sin(\frac{nx\pi}{\pi})]$$

Comment: Exactly. And this matches with Triatticus' comment.

Comment: can $$\int_{\frac{\pi}/3}^\pi (\pi-x)sin(\frac{nx\pi}{\pi})$$ then be rearranged to $$\int_{\frac{\pi}/3}^\pi {\pi}sin(\frac{nx\pi}{\pi}) + \int_{\frac{\pi}/3}^\pi (-x)sin(\frac{nx\pi}{\pi})$$ and then move the $\pi$ outside the integral as its a constant?

Comment: Exactly. That's perfect. And de "-" sign of x un the second integral can also be moved outside, getting  $$\pi\int_{\frac{\pi}{3}}^\pi\sin(nx)dx -\int x\sin(nx)dx$$

Comment: The limits in the second integral are the same, I forgot them, sorry.